# Why EF Cores CodeFirst does not respect HasPrecision?

Tags: entity-framework-core, decimal

I'am using EF Core (V5.0.5) Code First with MySql. For some properties in my entities I need decimal values with more decimal places than two. So I defined in `IEntityTypeConfiguartion`-class for example

```
builder.Property(dt => dt.Quantity)
       .HasPrecision(18, 10);
```

MySql Database Column is generated correctly, but when saved all values are truncated to 2 decimal places. I've found some hints for old EF versions and for SQLServer and also something related to this in github. But this has been solved several versions ago.

Did you have an idea what the problem is?

Best regards
Holger

Comment: Which of the [two providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'am using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 1):

Ivan Stoevs question lead to solution. By using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`problem has been solved